# How do I stop TypeScript errors when using Angular2 FormArray (v0.2.0)

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-forms

I'm using the Angular2 FormArray to create a dynamic form, which works fine, but I don't know how to fix the TypeScript error.

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(''),
  formItems: new FormArray([])
});
this.form.controls.formItems.push(...)
```

> Property 'formItems' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]:
>   AbstractControl; }'

---

**Fix below. Thanks to Harry Ninh and peeskillet**

```
this.itemsFormArray = new FormArray([]);

this.form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    formItems: this.payOffsFormArray
});

this.itemsFormArray.push(...)
```

Comment: Can you change it to `this.form.controls["formItems"].push(...)`?

Comment: @HarryNinh I think you still need to cast it first `(<FormArray>this.form.controls["formItems"]).push()`

Comment: Yea, to be completed it should be something like `(this.form.controls["formItems"] as FormArray).push(...)`. But I prefer to have a temporary variable for `FormArray` to easily add members before adding itself to `this.form`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Updated the post to show your comments help fix it.